# How do I display the current row value to info path form when creating custom workflow?

Tags: workflow, infopath

I am creating custom work flow for SharePoint 2010 site list. I have to display current row value to info path form.

If I use data connection it return full data from the list is that possible to filter it in to single row that should be a current workflow row value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you coding the workflow in Visual Studio or building one using SharePoint Designer?

If you are using Visual Studio you will be able to access the current item for which the workflow was started using the WorkflowProperties property.

How you surface this information in an InfoPath form depends on what purpose your infopath form has in your workflow.

Is it an instantiation/association form, or a Task Form?

Comment: i am creating it through sp designer.
its instantiation/association form...

The thing is if the user get the workflow task in his task he will not see the row value in approval form right. so i have to display the current row value in the approval workflow form.

Comment: Hm, I reckon Visual Studio workflows are the preferred method for using InfoPath Task Forms in your workflow, but here's a post on MSDN Forums which has some links relating to what you want, let us know if you're still stuck: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointworkflow/thread/3b02fc3c-9cc4-4955-98f6-413335c05733/